# How to save user data in firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

I want to save users data in firebase , should I save theme as map in database like this:

```
[
    {
    "id":1
    "name":"ab"
    "age" : 34
    }
    {
    "id":2
    "name":"aab"
    "age" : 4
    }
    {
    "id":3
    "name":"aeb"
    "age" : 25
    }

]
```

or there better idea to do that?

Comment: I would suggest you create a Users collection in Firestore and create a document for each user with the fields you need. If you need help using Firestore with Flutter you can check out this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=btZgitkRXXY).

Answer (score 0):

These types of incremental approaches aren't possible in **firebase firestore**. Alternatively, you can use a **firebase function** to add id while creating a new user. When a new document has been created the function will call the previous user-id as an integer and increment the id number by 1 and post it as the next user-id. But if you want to have the feature to delete the user document in the future then the id will be also removed as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use FireStore for such data.

Comment: why I cant use the normal database of firebase what the different

Comment: Firebase RTDB is just a big JSON file (if you want to make a change to this file, you need to download it and then edit it if it becomes huge). Suppose your app has 1 Million plus users and then you need to then access this one big JSON file, write custom rules so that only that particular user has access to this data etc. FireStore is mean to overcome some of the challenges of Firebase RTDB. Since you are saving user data, each user can be accesses with just a key.